# Unity not respecting HierarchicalLifetimeManager when manually registering UnityServiceLocator

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour in Unity when registering and resolving `IServiceLocator` using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.

What I'm seeing suggests that Unity treats the concrete type `UnityServiceLocator` as a special case when you register it. It treats the type as a static singleton, even when it shouldn't. This behaviour seems to be particular to `UnityServiceLocator`.

Background: I am slowly phasing out the "static" `ServiceLocator` in a few places in our code where it exists. The first step was going to be to register `IServiceLocator` in Unity and then have it injected as a dependency into those classes that use it.

In the following code, I register an injection factory to create a new instance of `UnityServiceLocator`. I also scope it with `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` to give me one instance per child container:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IServiceLocator>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionFactory(
            c =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("InjectionFactory invoked with container: " + c.GetHashCode());
                    return new UnityServiceLocator(c);
                }));

    container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>(); // expect to see console output here
    container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>(); // don't expect to see console output here

    var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
    child.Resolve<IServiceLocator>(); // expect to see console output here
    container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>(); // don't expect to see console output here

    var anotherChildContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
    anotherChildContainer.Resolve<IServiceLocator>(); // expect to see console output here
    anotherChildContainer.Resolve<IServiceLocator>(); // don't expect to see console output here
}
```

I would expect the above code to invoke the factory, create the `UnityServiceLocator` instance and write out console output three times, once for each container.
It doesn't - it does it once, as if I'd registered it as a singleton:

> InjectionFactory invoked with container: 20903718

It gets worse:

If I now make my own class implement `IServiceLocator` (literally, implement the interface, one ctor which takes `IUnityContainer`, and have all methods throw `NotImplementedException`), and swap the line

```
     return new UnityServiceLocator(c);
```

with

```
     return new MyUnityServiceLocator(c);
```

This starts behaving the way I'd expect:

```
InjectionFactory invoked with container: 20903718 
InjectionFactory invoked with container: 51746094 
InjectionFactory invoked with container: 41215084
```

I just cannot understand this behaviour unless Unity treats `UnityServiceLocator` as a special case.
Does anyone have any other explanation for this behaviour? Am I missing something obvious, or is Unity internally treating UnityServiceLocator as a special case and ignoring the lifetime strategy I am specifying?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but rather a suggestion: Don't inject the ServiceLocator, inject the actual dependency.

Comment: Thanks Alex - in fact this is what is being done now, but I wanted to get from static service locator to proper constructor injection in a series of small safe steps. The first of these was to inject in the service locator rather than use the static approach of getting it, thus only making one relatively minor change at a time. Once I'd noticed this odd behaviour though, I felt compelled to drill into it a bit further, as it seemed so curious!

Comment: UnityServiceLocator is not treated in any special way; you can check the Unity source to confirm. This is a weird one.

Comment: It turns out the UnityServiceLocator is treated in a special way - it registers itself with the container with ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager in its own constructor. See Randy Levy's comment here: http://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/12727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `UnityServiceLocator` is a special case - it registers *itself* with `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` in it's own constructor when it is first created.

See Randy Levy's comment here for more information: [unity.codeplex.com/workitem/12727](https://web.archive.org/web/20160628030927/unity.codeplex.com/workitem/12727)